# How do I list the jobs I've submitted to AWS Rekognition, especially StartPersonTracking?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-rekognition

While developing a Lambda Function (I'm new to AWS), I've submitted a couple of jobs to Rekognition without recording the jobId.

Are there any methods of obtaining the jobIds so I can download the person tracking json? I've gone through the documentation, but I'm unable to find anything that works for me.